# How safetly remove links on paperclip attachmetns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

I have Paperclip attachment manager with mysql database.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :file, :styles => {:large => "800x600>"}, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

end
```

Images stored in Amazon S3. I need remove links on this images from database, but images must stay on S3. How I can do this?

1) Photo.delete_all?

2) Delete from ActiveAdmin?

3) Delete from mysql console?

4) Some another method......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make the file_url blank for all no need to delete all photo

```
Photo.update_all(file: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

> [`keep_old_files`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file):
>
> Keep the existing attachment files (original + resized) from being automatically deleted when an attachment is cleared or updated. Defaults to false.

So maybe you could use:

```
#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :file,
      styles: {:large => "800x600>"},
      default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
      keep_old_files: true

end
```

...or even better:

> [`preserve_files`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file)
>
> Keep the existing attachment files in all cases, even if the parent record is destroyed.

```
#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :file,
      styles: {:large => "800x600>"},
      default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
      preserve_files: true

end
```